# I can't use fabric in opera, chrome or safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem with fabricj and canvas. I write functions:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

jq().ready(function(){

    jq("#addText").click(function(){

        var text = new fabric.Text(jq("#textCanvas").val(), { left: 0, top: 0 });
        text.setColor(jq("#textColor option:checked").val());
        text.setFontSize(jq("#textSize option:checked").val());
        text.setFontFamily(jq("#fontFamily option:checked").val());
        canvas.add(text);
    })
```

jq is no conflict with $.
When I try add text in firefox I can, but when I try in Opera, Chrome, or Safari I can't. I have not got information about bugs.

Have you any idea?

Comment: In general terms, it's very unlikely that a well known library just does not work at all in most major browsers and nobody noticed. What exactly prevents you from adding text in Opera, Chrome and Safari?

Comment: What does you Console says?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the canvas.renderAll() method.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

$().ready(function(){

$("#addText").click(function(){

    var text = new fabric.Text($("#textCanvas").val(), { left: 0, top: 0 });
   // text.setColor($("#textColor option:checked").val());
   // text.setFontSize($("#textSize option:checked").val());
   // text.setFontFamily($("#fontFamily option:checked").val());
    canvas.add(text);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
});
```

See working [example](http://jsbin.com/piruduvipi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)